# React Native run-android always launch emulator even when android device connected

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, npm, metro-bundler

I'm new to react native, I am having this issue when running the command npm react-native run-android it always launch an emulator, even my android device is connected and displayed in adb devices list when running `adb devices` command.

My Environment : 
OS : Windows 10 
NPM : 6.14.4
Node : v10.21.0

Comment: Are you sure device is connected via ADB ? Check with command : `adb devices`

Comment: i already mentioned in my post "my android device is connected and displayed in adb devices list."

Answer (score 5):

Disable USB debugging on your device settings and enable it again.